# IF command not working when using 'NOT or '==' to use CALL and use SET for setting a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm creating a simple program that will echo variables from `SET /p` strings into a nice, neat list. However, I am having trouble creating 2 working `IF` statements, one using `NOT`, and one using `==` to detect if one of my variables, `%pwad%`, is empty, or contains values. I want to use what the `IF` statement returns to set variable `%finalpwad%` to either `"No pwad detected"` or `%pwad%`.

How should I properly write this statement? Where might I need corrections, fixing the `IF` statements or maybe even the part where it sets `%pwad%` to `%finalpwad%`?

I have already tried fixing my `call` part and what they call from, but to no avail. I'm almost sure this is an `IF` statement issue, as I'm not too good with them, and always struggle reading the notes about the command from `IF /?`.

Here's a snippet of my code and the source of the problem I am having:

```
set /p pwad=Set a pwad (or none): 

if %pwad% NOT [] call :yespwad & pause
if %pwad% == [] :nopwad & pause

:nopwad
set finalpwad=No pwad detected
goto :printout

:yespwad
set finalpwad=%pwad%
goto :printout
```

I expect the output to continue onto `:printout`, where it echoes all the variables the user enters, but it instead exits the program, and makes it so I can't find out whether it properly read my `IF NOT` or `IF ==` statements. I rudimentarily added pauses to snuff out the problem and see where the source was, and I concluded it must the `IF` statements.

Comment: not sure if your issue but you're missing a call here "f %pwad% == [] :nopwad & pause"   probably can delete that whole line

Comment: I see you did not look at the help file for the `IF` command as it clearly shows the proper syntax for comparing strings. `IF [NOT] string1==string2 command`. It is recommended that you use quotes as well when comparing strings.  `IF  "string1"=="string2" command`. IF comparisons are literal. Each side of the comparison has to match. Using brackets does not check for an empty string. There also is an option to check if a variable is defined. `IF DEFINED VAR command`.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help file clearly shows the proper syntax for comparing strings.

> ```
> IF [NOT] string1==string2 command
> ```

It is recommended that you use quotes as well when comparing strings.

> ```
> IF "string1"=="string2" command
> ```

`IF` comparisons are literal. Each side of the comparison has to match. Using brackets does not check for an empty string.

There also is an option to check if a variable is defined.

> ```
> IF DEFINED VAR command
> ```

Looking at your logic you could essentially do this:

```
@echo off

set /p "pwad=Set a pwad (or none): "

IF DEFINED pwad (
    set "finalpwad=%pwad%"
) ELSE (
    set "finalpwad=No pwad detected"
)
```

Comment: It is also recommended to add some spaces after `==` like `if "str1" == "str2"` because command line interpreter will interpret it like this, anyway.